# Adding multiple thematic maps in a single Layout with MapInfo 19

Tags: mapinfo, layouts

I am a former MapInfo user. Back with MapInfo after 5 years in the ESRI environment, I was hired by a consulting company that uses MapInfo version 19.
I collaborated in a project in which I must create thematic maps with 5 variables to represent cleanliness in 19 boroughs.

To be able to compare the 5 thematic variables side by side, I was asked to represent them on a single layout.

How can I achieve this cartographic and thematic representation in MapInfo version 19?

Regards,

Comment: If you have a layout, you can add multiple maps to the page, and for each map show a different thematic map. Is that what you a looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the MapInfo's function which allows to carry out this operation. It's the ***Tile*** function in the ***window*** menu.
As simple as that!

Kind regards,